# Nancyfx forms authentication per module can't not work

Tags: forms-authentication, nancy

There are several modules and I only need the forms authentication works for special module, I wrote the codes like this:

```
protected override void RequestStartup(TinyIoCContainer requestContainer, IPipelines pipelines, NancyContext context)
{
    base.RequestStartup(requestContainer, pipelines, context);

    var waiterModule = GetModule(typeof(WaitersModule), context);
    FormsAuthentication.Enable(waiterModule, new FormsAuthenticationConfiguration {
        RedirectUrl = "~/waiters/login",
        UserMapper = requestContainer.Resolve<IUserMapper>()
    });
}
```

And the module like this:

```
public WaitersModule() : base("/waiters")
{
    Get["/profile"] = parameters =>
    {
        this.RequiresAuthentication();

        return View["profile", model];
    };
}
```

But it did not redirect to the login page, just return HTTP code 401.

Is there any mistake in my codes?

Comment: I'm not sure if this also work for forms authetication, but for stateless authentication I had to do the .Enable in the Modules Constructor, not in the BootStrapper.